# Dagger2 complains after ProGuard rules are applied

Tags: android, proguard, dagger-2, android-proguard, dagger

On official [Dagger2 documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) is written that there are no specific ProGuard settings and should follow settings relevant using Dagger.

After enabling ProGuard Dagger2 starts to complaint that cannot find classes to inject etc. `lt.setkus.myapp.data.rest.b.c cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.` So, should I keep all classes untouched by ProGuard which Dagger2 uses for DI?

Rules from Dagger 1.x applied on project:

```
-keep class dagger.** { *; }
-keep interface dagger.** { *; }

-keep class **$$ModuleAdapter { *; }
-keepnames class **$$InjectAdapter { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javax.inject.Inject <fields>;
    @javax.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}
```

Comment: you don't need rules for Dagger2. But do you keep your pojos or is that obfuscated

Comment: lt.setkus.myapp.data.rest.b.c. What do you have under the package just retain them with -keep class lt.setkus.myapp.data.**.rest.** {*; } and then try again

Comment: It was one error sample of many. It looks like I have to keep all classes and interfaces which are involved to build the object graph by Dagger2. Is it common practise to do so?

Comment: probably. i have used retrofit and other 3 party libs with dagger2 so provide rules for them and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because Dagger 2 uses codegen, and (unlike Dagger 1) doesn't use class names or other String keys anywhere, you shouldn't need *any* of those Dagger 1.x rules. You'll need your standard Android rules that keep reflectively-created Activity and Fragment instances (etc), but as far as I know Dagger doesn't require anything special as of Dagger 2's initial release.

The bizarre thing here is that it looks like the Dagger compiler is running *after* ProGuard's shrinking and obfuscation steps, where you really want to run Dagger first and ProGuard second. This ensures Dagger can use the fields and constructors it needs, and that ProGuard can shrink Dagger's output.

Check your build settings to ensure that Proguard is run immediately before dexing and APK creation, and that Dagger is run before ProGuarding and not after.

Comment: Hi @Jeff Bowman. I have separated app logic into different submodules. Some dependencies are defined in submodule. Moreover, all these classes which Dagger cannot find because of obfuscation are in submodule. Could this be a reason of issue? If yes, how possibly I could change settings to ensure that ProGuard runs after Dagger2?

Comment: @RobertasSetkus It sounds like you're running ProGuard on each submodule, rather than on your application as a whole. Is this intended?

Comment: Firstly, I enabled and started adding rules only to application module. Cannot remember what problem I was dealing with but just noticed if I enable ProGuard and add necessary rules it makes an effect. Now I completely disabled and moved some rules to the application module and it seems works. Passes obfuscation phase successfully. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffBowman how Check your build settings to ensure that Proguard is run immediately before dexing and APK creation

Comment: @yousef Depends on your build configuration (Ant? Gradle? etc), which clearly won't fit in these comments. Please ask a new question, link to this answer, and include the relevant parts of your build file. (If you want, you can also include the text of your error message, so readers can ensure you're solving the right problem.)